# Trying out with some code to make use of multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I have an app that can spawn any given number of threads. So I'd like this code to become multithreaded

```
void *some_thread_fuction(void *param)
{
    struct some_struct *obj=(struct some_struct *)param;
    int m=obj->m;
    int n=...
    double t[m+2][n+2]={0};
    
    for (i=0; i <= m+1; i++) {
        for (j=0; j <= n+1; j++) {
            t[i][j] = 30.0;
        }
    }


    for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
        t[i][0] = 40.0;
        t[i][n+1] = 90.0;
    }
    for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
        t[0][j] = 30.0;
        t[m+1][j] = 50.0;
    }
    memcpy(global_t,t,...);
}
```

I am having simple reasoning issue as to why I like to make this a multi-threaded program. but it make sense because if I have 5 threads (assumed I am taking how many number of threads to spawn at program start in program parameter) and n=20 m=20 which is also fed at program start as parameters then I can try working on 0-4 in one thread, 5-8 in second thread and so on until 16-20 in last iteration of first loop(just an example, because m=etc n=etc and number of threads can be anything values fed by user).

But more importantly I am having tough time as to how to even dissect the three `for` loops to distribute the processing over amount of work to multiple threads to completion of all the loops in this code. This is simple code, so it's just a real world example that I am having difficulty understanding how to do it in code for a threaded program for this scenario.

Comment: So you want to spawn threads and give start and end offset in the matrix as thread arguments?

Comment: @kiner_shah sounds like u understood. Thanks for comment

Comment: @kiner_shah its simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this piece of code into a function:

```
    for (i=0; i <= m+1; i++) {
        for (j=0; j <= n+1; j++) {
            t[i][j] = 30.0;
        }
    }
```

as follows:

```
void initialize(double t[], int start_i, int end_i, int n) {
    for (i=start_i; i <= end_i; i++) {
        for (j=0; j <= n+1; j++) {
            t[i][j] = 30.0;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then split the interval [0 m+1] into as 5 intervals and call the initialize function from each thread for each interval.

That said, there must be more efficient ways to achieve the same thing using some copy instructions.

Comment: Please do tell so do I need to implement function for 40 90 50 myself. Did u left it as an exercise for me. Or I can use same function to edit values which I think so.

Comment: Well, I am certain you got the idea.